# Prevent LaTex code from showing in report

Tags: latex, r-markdown

In my markdown file I use the latex command

```
$$\pagebreak$$
```

to force a page break.

The page break works fine but the latex code also shows up in my report.
I want to let the code work but hide it in the report.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try using `\pagebreak` without the `$$` tags.

Comment: That worked thank you. But with the comment to always leave a blank line above and below.
Can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$$` tags are used to enter and exit math mode for writing equations.  Since you are executing a typesetting command, you need to use `\pagebreak` without the `$$` tags.

As noted in your comment, blank lines around the tag are necessary.